# Hu moment program works on png but not jpg

Tags: python, opencv, png, jpeg

I currently have two codes. One generates 50 random images of coloured circles on a black background and one image of a coloured rectangle on a black background. The sizes and colours vary. I am currently using Hu moments to be able to find the image containing the rectangle. The problem I am running into is that the program for some reason only works with .png pictures and not .jpg pictures. Is there some difference on how opencv reads these files to be causing it? It goes as far as that if it is a jpg picture then it breaks the code due to some of the moments being equal to zero, so when I try to do a log transform it does not work.

```
 import glob
 import cv2
 import math
 import os
 pictures=(glob.glob("./*.png"))
 values=[]
 for i in pictures:   #goes through the pictures in the folder and calculates their hu moments
    img = cv2.imread(i, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    z,img = cv2.threshold(img,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    moments = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(img)).flatten()
    adjusted=[]
    print(moments)
    for j in moments: #log adjusts the moments so that they are easier to read
       try:
          adjusted.append(-1*math.copysign(1.0,j)*math.log10(abs(j)))
       except:
          print('')
    values.append(moments)
 average=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

 for i in values: #next two for loops find the average of the all of the hu moments
    for j in range(7):
       average[j]=average[j]+i[j]

 for i in range(7):
    average[i]=average[i]/51

 diff=[]
 for i in values: #finds the total difference for each hu moment and the average
    total=0
    for j in range(7):
       total=abs(i[j]-average[j])+total
       #print (total)
    diff.append(total)
 print (diff)
 candidate=diff.index(max(diff)) #finds which picture had the highest difference from average
 print(diff.index(max(diff)))
 print(pictures[candidate])
 img = cv2.imread(pictures[candidate]) #opens the image to show the sqaure image
 cv2.imshow("sqaure image", img)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So as mentioned before, this code only works for png pictures, but does not work for jpg. Does anyone know why this is? Also if you want the program that creates the images I can upload that too.

Comment: What error/traceback are you getting?

Comment: Some comments in your code might help you and others understand what you are trying to achieve and what your assumptions are.

Comment: PNG is lossless and JPEG is lossy.  JPEG images most likely will have small perturbations in uniform areas which may cause havoc in your algorithm if it is sensitive to minute differences.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added some comments if something is still unclear please tell me

Comment: @Will sorry I can't run the code right now so I cant copy it directly but it was a math error, due to trying to take the log10 of zero. For some reason in a jpg when converting to a binary, 0 would be the value for many of the hu moments

Comment: How about providing a PNG and JPG of the an image that has problems?

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov interesting. I'm not that familiar with cv2 but I would have imagined it would use an internal normalised bitmap structure once an image was loaded from whatever format.

Comment: So i think I know what was causing it. I think it was because of the binary threshold some of the images ended up being pure black, which was causing the issue